# Remove last letter word if preceded with number from dataframe column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Input

```
   Column
0   2 mm
1   3 kg
2   4 m
3   name
4   2 mm
5   3 mph
6   full
7   left
```

Here I need to remove Units from the table.
I tried with

```
df["Column"] = df["Column"].replace("\D", "", regex = True)
```

It gives me wrong output.

Expected Output:

```
    Column
0   2
1   3
2   4
3   name
4   2
5   3
6   full
7   left
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df["Column"] = df["Column"].str.replace(r'(\d)\s*[a-zA-Z]+$', r'\1', regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YqutzZ/2). *Regex details*:

- `(\d)` - Group 1 (the `\1` numbered backreference refers to this group value from the replacement pattern): any digit
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

You still can use your `replace`

```
s = df.Column.replace('[^0-9]+','',regex=True)
df.Column = df.Column.mask(s!='',s)
Out[27]: 
0          2
1          3
2          4
3       name
4          2
5          3
6       full
7       left
Name: Column, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.extract`: if the row begins by a number `^\d+`, get it or `|` keep the entire row `.*`.

```
df['Column'] = df['Column'].str.extract(r'(^\d+|.*)')
print(df)

# Output
  Column
0      2
1      3
2      4
3   name
4      2
5      3
6   full
7   left
```